# How to run code from sql server in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Developer from Stackoverflow 
 where UserID='786' and Developer='Sufiyan'", con);
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
    con.Open();
 }
 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.Read())
 {
    string codeSnippet = reader["CodeSnippet"].ToString();
    dynamic script = 
     CSScript.LoadCode(@"
     using System;
     using System.Windows.Forms;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Windows.Forms;
     using System.Data.SqlClient;
     public class RunFromSqlServer
     {
       public void RunCode(string developer){" + codeSnippet + "}"+
               "}").CreateObject("*");script.RunCode("Mohammad Sufiyan Shaikh");
 }
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
 {
    con.Close();
 }
```

where codeSnippet can be any c# code you want to run
i have posted this question with answer to help others..

Comment: Exactly what is trying to be achieved by this?  At the moment, it scares me just a bit.  Is this a question?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes! this is question but with answer

Comment: If you are answering your own question then this belongs on a community wiki.  Posting questions with answers can become a bit too confusing otherwise.  For example, how are you going to select an answer?

Comment: You just load a code snippet from somewhere and run it. I may be loaded from anywhere, from mysql, file, network, etc. it is not a magic

Answer (score 1):

You can't really mix and match SQL and c# code like that. There is a way of running .net code on SQL server 2005+ by using a feature called SQL CLR but there are limitations to what you can do.  Here is a tutorial: [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](https://web.archive.org/web/20150112060421/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx) ([original link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

There are other things you can create such as SQL CLR triggers and Stored procedures. Research SQL CLR for more info.

Comment: Thank You Sir i will see to it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that CS-Script existed before I read this question. Very interesting technology. From the documentation it seems that you are using it a wrong.

http://www.csscript.net/help/script_hosting_guideline_.html

You should be doing something like this:

```
var result = CSScript.Eval("Mohammad Sufiyan Shaikh",
                            @"func(string user) {"
                                  + codeSnippet + ");
                              }");
```

Comment: Thank You but according to my requirement this is the only way i found.....the example above is just a test example and the real code what i want i have with me.this post is just for helping others developer like me...so that they can get some idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty cool, but I doubt that it is very useful since you lose much of the good stuff you get from compiled code. For instance your program would crash suddenly if someone would insert code with bad syntax into the database table.

Comment: Thank You Sir @mikeng i m the only one to insert code into the database

Comment: Yes ok, but why not just write the code you want to have executed as separate classes that can be compiled and unit tested together with the rest of your code? Is it because it's a convenient distribution mechanism, and you want to avoid to redistribute a new version of your application every time, or what's the reason.